# NonLinearModelFit to a Function

Tags: function-construction, fitting

I have a multiple dimension function that is fairly complicated.  Instead of simply using `Series` to get a taylor series of the function, I would rather specify my own nonlinear model to fit to the function.

In the past I have done this simply by collecting data at various points in the function, however that was always with a one dimensional function so it was easy to create a {x,f(x)} pairs for the data.

Now that I have multiple independent variables I need assistance using the `NonlinearModelFit` function:

1. Is it possible to easily create a list of the following type if given the function f?

   ```
   {{x1,y1,f(x1,y1)},{x2,y2,f(x2,y2)},...}
   ```
2. Is it possible to use `NonLinearModelFit` directly with the function itself?  If so how would I do that?

Comment: 1. Use `Table[]`, possibly with `Flatten[]`. 2. Yes, look at the docs for `FindFit[]` and `NonlinearModelFit[]` for multivariate examples.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't see because it wasn't in the details or Examples, but I see they have addressed the problem under Scope.  Thanks!